# How long should a tap last for android?

Tags: javascript, android, ruby, selenium, tap

Trying to understand something in a code I've just seen. To implement a "tap", the following code is written:

```
driver.mouse_down(...)
sleep(1)
driver.mouse_down(...)
```

My question is how it can be known that the sleep is long enough? Can I make it shorter? Is there a standard about minimal tap time etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no minimum tap time used by the Android platform.  There are longer times for detecting things like long presses, which are defined by http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html

Comment: so, just to understand you better - you say that there is no amount for a minimal tap time? if so - how much time should a test wait between mouse down to mouse up? is my question well-formed/appropriate at all?

Comment: There is nothing in the standard platform that rejects a tap because it was "too short."  You don't need to wait between events.  There is no minimum tap time.